# The word "royal"

Tags: pronunciation

I noticed this because of the Youtube videos about the to-be-released Pokemon game. There is a new battling style called "Battle Royal" and in those videos they pronounce royal as "roi-aww," putting the stress at the 2nd syllable.

Is this a non-English word or does it have other meanings? I went online but there is only info about the royal I familiar with. Thanks.

For your kind reference, you may want to check out the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvSgH-48kXs at 5:03 on Youtube.

Comment: This is interesting to me, often the word "Royale" is pronounced like this as in "eggs royale" but it seems that either pronunciation has become acceptable for either word - this both intrigues and infuriates me, because it just seems like people who pronunce "Royal" as "Royale" just sound pretentious. Hm.

Comment: I made this question because I have heard even more people saying this. You may check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQCmdCnMU_0 at 1:20 and he also pronounced it as if royale. Based on my understanding, royale is something royal (just like rational and rationale, final and finale). But we won't pronounce rationale as rational. So that's my question.

Comment: By the way, I just found that the word royale is red-zigzagged, probably meaning that this is not an English word!

Comment: Oh, yes, I should have mentioned, Royale is from french but commonly used in names etc. (eg. Battle Royale, Eggs Royale)

Comment: Then I would think because the position of "royale" is after the noun, it is French (which is unlike "Mission Possible" that the adjective is behind the noun), and in French we put the adjective after the noun. So it simply means Royal Battle...

Comment: Oiu! I am inclined to agree with you on that one! That reasoning is sound, actually, I might actually consider that a safe answer to go with.

Comment: Unlike smaller skirmishes, a Battle Royale involved considerable resources and possible risk to the State and the boundaries of the monarchy itself. Sound reasonable? I just made it up.

Comment: There's not much info about the battling style but simply judging from the video, it may have been a 1:1:1:1 battle (unlike ordinary 1:1 battle). Well then I guess would a Battle Royale is something French or whatever? But I can't still understand why the "e" at the end was missed out in the icon...